# Using plot_click in flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

Is there a way to have plots with mouse interactions using flexdashboard?

In shiny this is not difficult. I want to save mouse clicks, and in shiny UI I would use:

```
mainPanel(plotOutput("scatterplot", click = "plot_click"))
```

And in the server you would have:

```
df <- reactiveValues(Clicksdf = data.frame(clickx = numeric(), clicky = numeric()))
```

Can I do this in flexdashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the code chunk as if it were both the Shiny UI and server:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
plotOutput("plot1", click = "wt")
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
  plot(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$wt)
  })
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
renderText({
  unlist(input$wt$x)
})
```
````

Comment: I marked it as the accepted answer.  Unfortunately this is my first post, so I don't have enough reputation to upvote it, but when i do, I will come back and upvote it.  Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. Thank you!